# Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException on action.SendKeys after following link?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having some issues using selenium, and specifically using actions, although this could just be a symptom for a bigger issue. To quickly explain what try to do:

1. I scroll down to the bottom of a page using SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown)
2. I press a button, and I change the page to a different language.
3. I try to scroll down on the new page using SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown). This is where i receive an error!

The strange thing here is that i have no issues with the scrolling in step 1 even though I am using the same function, but in step 3 i receive an error message:

OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 'The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed'

I have tried to redeclare my footer variable, and also included it as a Footer class variable (originally it wasn't), but nothing i do change anything

The reason I am using SendKeys and not MoveToElement is due to MoveToElement doesn't work for off-screen elements in Firefox. I have included all relevant code below, including an image of the error and when it happens.

Could anyone please advice what I am doing wrong?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Reset_newsletter_subscription_form_BR_site()
    {
        Browser.Goto(siteUrl);
        Webpage.Footer.GoTo_CountryPageViaFooter("br");
        Webpage.Footer.ScrollToFooter(); // -> This is where it fails!
        Other.Irrelevant.Stuff();
    }
```

Below this is the Selenium parts:

```
public static class Browser
{
    public static IWebDriver webDriver;
    public static Actions actions;

    public static void Goto(string url)
    {
        webDriver.Url = url;
    }
}

public static class Webpage
{
    public static Footer Footer
    {
        get
        {
            var footer = new Footer(Browser.webDriver, Browser.actions);
            return footer;
        }
     }
 }

public class Footer
{
    private IWebDriver webDriver;
    private Actions actions;
    private IWebElement footer;

    public Footer(IWebDriver webDriver, Actions actions)
    {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
        this.actions = actions;
    }
    public void GoTo_CountryPageViaFooter(string CountryTag)
    {

        footer = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("c-footer"));
        var changeCountryButton = footer.FindElement(By.ClassName("c-footer__toggle-country-selector"));

        ScrollToFooter();

        actions.MoveToElement(footer).Perform();
        actions.MoveToElement(changeCountryButton).Perform();
        changeCountryButton.Click();

        var intPageLink = footer.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@href='/" + CountryTag + "/']"));
        intPageLink.Click();
    }

    public void ScrollToFooter()
    {

        footer = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("c-footer"));

        //MoveToElement does not work for Firefox, so a workaround is needed.
        if (webDriver is FirefoxDriver)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 5)
            {
                actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Perform(); //This is where it fails!
                i++;
            }
        }

        actions.MoveToElement(footer).Perform();
    }
```

[Image of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e9d0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever Perform() method is invoked, it figures how to interact with the Page. So its job is to find out the active element present in the Page(if element not specified as in MoveToElement(element) or during clicking an element using Actions).

So in your case, as no Element is specified `actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Perform();` so Actions will focus on any Active Element present in the Page and Perform the SendKeys Operation on that.

[Details about Actions Interaction with Web Page..](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Advanced-User-Interactions)

So, as soon as the Language change link is getting clicked the Elements attached to the DOM are changing as a result Selenium Webdriver detects this as a change in the current Active Element as a result **StaleElementReference Exception** thrown.

In order to get rid of the Exception, you can add wait statement in between or there is a great way to [handle StaleElementReference Exception given here](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2012/06/staleelementexception.html)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `.SendKeys()` to scroll the page. It won't be consistent. Imagine if the page is longer or shorter... how many times will you need to scroll? I think a better approach is to use JS to scroll the page to the desired element.

```
public void ScrollToFooter()
{
    footer = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("c-footer"));

    // MoveToElement does not work for Firefox, so a workaround is needed
    if (webDriver is FirefoxDriver)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
        jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", footer);
    }
    else
    {
        actions.MoveToElement(footer).Perform();
    }
}
```

If you decide to stick with your method, you have a bug because of a missing `else`. If the driver is FF, after your scrolldown code is executed, it will execute `.MoveToElement()` and fail.

You could simplify this function to just use JS for all drivers.

```
public void ScrollToFooter()
{
    footer = webDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("c-footer"));
    IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
    jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", footer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I will definitely try your way. The .MoveToElement() at the end will work if the element in question i on screen at that time (or for all other browsers), so I left it without else on purpose, but I agree that it might not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Perform();
```

I suggest:

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
```